# How to get a variable out of the query block in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have this code:

```
conn.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM test', (err, rows) => {
let count = rows[0].count;
console.log(count);  });
```

Instead of console logging the count value, I want to store the value in a global variable to be able to use it anywhere else in the code (anywhere outside the query block). How is it possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Define a variable in outer scope and use `async/await`. but unless you don't have other option avoid using global variable

Answer (score 0):

You do have several ways. The one you are asking is the following:

```
var result;
conn.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM test', (err, rows) => {
  result = rows[0].count;
});
```

This will do what you are asking but the issue is that the code of `conn.query` is async, which means that outside, if you want to use `result` you have no idea of when it will be ready.

In these cases you can perhaps use some async management, like a promise for example, because the usage of global variables is not a best practice:

```
function countTests() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM test', (err, rows) => {
      resolve(result);
    });  
  });
}
countTests().then(result => { console.log('results:', result); });
```

You can even implement it with `async/await` if you want to assign it like:

```
const results = await countTests();
```

wrapping this code in an `async` block

Comment: Not really familiar with promises, as I am new to nodeJS sorry.
All I want to do is store the count value in a var and perform a few if condition checks. Is this the only way out?

Comment: the first example doesn't use promises. Just put your checks inside the callback.

Comment: Used that thanks, but since I am using intervals (5 seconds), the first result is always undefined but it works (returns actual count value later on) :|

Of course I get that it's because we have not defined the value of result initially so it will return undefined. Any way to fix that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: actually, that's a crazy approach, polling for an async action, it would be better that you give a look to promises, the management of async code will be always useful in your future. If you want to go on with intervals, and you need a single check, at least clear the interval after you did it

Comment: Thanks, will do so then!